# Is it possible to have a Flexbox inside of a Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

*self teaching myself html/css thorugh mozilla and CSS tricks*

I currently have this:
[image]

and want this:
[image]

I assumed it would be the same process, but nothing inside of the pink div will show

HTML:

```
<div class="stack-1">
            <div class="flexbox">
                <div class="left">
                  <div class="flex-inside">
                    <div class="pos-inside">
                      <div class="icon-1">
```

CSS: **issue with 'pos-inside' and '.icon-1'**

```
.stack-1{
    display:flex;
    background:green;
}
.flexbox{
    display: flex;
    background: purple;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}
.thomas, .broke{
    width: 50%;
    height: 30px;
}
.left{
    background-color: brown;
}
.right{
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: flex;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.flex-inside{
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  background: navy;
  width: 60%;
  height: 30px;
}
.flex-right{
  
  background: hotpink;
  width: 60%;
  height: 30px;
  
}
.pos-inside{
  color: orange;
<!--just trying out any heights-->
  width: 40%;
  height: 20px;
}
.icon-1{
  color: purple;
<!--just trying out any heights-->
  width: 10%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to put a flexbox inside a flexbox. As a practical example, on this very stackoverflow page (in its current implementation as I write this answer, at least), we have

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    ...


with the CSS rules

body {
  display: flex;
}
body>.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

As for your particular example, your `.left` div will have a width of 0, because no width is specified and there's no content. Now notice that its child div, with `.flex-inside`, has a width of 60%. This is 60% of 0, so its width will be 0 as well, and so on down the line.

Try

```
.left{
    background-color: brown;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Alternatively, leave `.left` alone and try giving a specific width to `.flex-inside`:

```
.flex-inside{
  ...
  width: 120px;
}
```

As for `.pos-inside` and `.icon-1`, did you really mean `color: ...`, or did you mean `background: ...`? Again, there's no content, so setting the text colour won't have any effect. Either change the property to `background:`, or add some text in the div to see what happens.

Comment: Thank you, I failed to realize that because there's no content it would be a background and my left had no width